Turborepo / Lamda / Dockerfile - Error Not Finding Internal Package
I have a monorepo using Turborepo that has a Lambda function that depends on an internal package. Basically, something like the following structure...
The service is "resize" and it depends on "@repo/image".
services
  resize
    package.json
    Dockerfile
    src
      index.ts
packages
  image
    package.json
    src
      helper.ts

This is simplified of course.
The docker file for the "resize" service looks like this (based on the docker example from turborepo)...
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/nodejs:20 as base

FROM base AS builder
WORKDIR ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
RUN npm i turbo --global
COPY . .
RUN turbo prune resize --docker

FROM base AS installer
WORKDIR ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
COPY .gitignore .gitignore
COPY --from=builder /${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/out/json/ .
COPY --from=builder /${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/out/package-lock.json ./package-lock.json
RUN npm i
COPY --from=builder /${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/out/full/ .
COPY turbo.json turbo.json
RUN npm run build -- --filter=resize...

FROM base AS runner
WORKDIR ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

RUN ls ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

COPY --from=installer /${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/services/resize/package.json .
COPY --from=installer /${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/services/resize/dist/index.js .

RUN ls ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

CMD [ "index.handler" ]

When I build and deploy the Lambda function with the docker container, I get an error indicating it cannot find the internal package "@repo/image".
The example for Docker from Turborepo is for a NextJS app, so I must be missing something here. I am not an advanced Docker user, so there may be something else going on. The command I use to build the Docker image is...
docker build --platform linux/amd64 -f services/resize/Dockerfile . -t resizeservice --no-cache

I have seen examples using the "serverless" framework, but I am looking to use the Docker approach with CDK as my deployment approach.
Thanks for any help you can provide.
